# A statement reciprocal to Schur's First Lemma

Tags: group-theory

What the mathematicians call *Schur's lemma* is known to physicists as *Schur's second lemma*:

- An intertwiner of two irreducible representations of a group is
  either zero or isomorphism.

It is valid for all dimensionalities -- finite, countable,
uncountable.

The following statement goes in physics books under the name of
*Schur's first lemma*:

- An intertwiner from an irreducible representation to itself is a scalar times the identity operator.

It is almost trivial in finite dimensions, while its generalisation to countable dimensions makes *[Dixmier's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297283/dixmiers-lemma-as-a-generalisation-of-schurs-first-lemma)* (which fails in uncountable dimensions).

Now, the statement reciprocal to Schur'r first lemma:

- If a unit operator is the only one (up to multiplication by a number) which commutes with all operators of a fully reducible representation, then the representation is irreducible.

The proof is straightforward:

Let $\,{\mathbb{A}}\,$ be the said irreducible representation, with an element $\,g\,$ of the group $\,G\,$ mapped to an operator $\,{\mathbb{A}}_g\,$.
Were the representation reducible, the representation space $\,V\,$ would have had a nontrivial invariant subspace $V_1$. Let $\,{\mathbb{P}}_1\,$ be a projector onto it:  $\;{\mathbb{P}}_1\,v\,\in V_1\,$, for $\,\forall v\in V\,$.
The full reducibility implies that if $\,v=v_1+v_2\,$, with $\,v_1\in V_1\,$ and $\,v_2\in{V/V_1}\,$, then $\,{\mathbb{A}}_g\,v\,=\,{\mathbb{A}}_g\,v_1\,+\,{\mathbb{A}}_g\,v_2\;$, where $\,{\mathbb{A}}_g\,v_1\in V_1\,$ and $\,{\mathbb{A}}_g\,v_2\in{V/V_1}\,$. In concise notation,
$$
 {\mathbb{A}}_g\,{\mathbb{P}}_1\,v\,=\, {\mathbb{P}}_1\,{\mathbb{A}}_g\,v\;,\;\;\forall g\in G\;\,.
 $$
It was assumed that only a unit operator (up to multiplication by a number) has this property. This operator can coincide with $\, {\mathbb{P}}_1\,$ only if $\,V_1=V\,$, i.e., only if the representation is irreducible.

Is my understanding correct that this proof applies to any dimensions, including noncountable?

Comment: @freakish : The part about scalars doesn't work in arbitrary dimensions (simply because you may fail to find an eigenvector of the intertwiner in question). The fact that it works in countable dimension takes more work than finite dimensions and crucially relies on the difference of cardinality with $\mathbb C$. Also, the word "intertwiner" is common, especially in physics and related areas

Comment: OP : you are correct, although perhaps it should be noted that in other contexts (such as positive characteristic dividing the order of the group) the assumption of complete reducibility, even in finite dimensions, is a pretty strong one.

Comment: Can I just point out that Schur's first and second lemma combined form Schur's lemma according to mathematicians. The most basic version of Schur's lemma states that if $k$ is algebraically closed and $V$ is completely reducible, then $\mathrm{End}_k(V)\cong k$ if and only if $V$ is simple. The fact that these must therefore consist of scalars is clear. Schur's lemma is a name given to a collection of statements with this in their kernel, with varying levels of generalization. But what happens with $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$ is part of Schur's lemma.