# Dixmier's lemma as a generalisation of Schur's first lemma

Tags: group-theory, operator-theory, representation-theory

What mathematicians call *Schur's lemma* is known to physicists as *Schur's second lemma*:

- An intertwiner of two irreducible representations of a group is
  either zero or isomorphism.

It is valid for all dimensionalities -- finite, countable,
   uncountable.

The following statement is referred to in physics books as
   *Schur's first lemma*:

- An intertwiner from an irreducible representation to itself is a scalar times the identity operator.

In finite dimensions, the latter lemma easily follows from the former one:

- Let $\,{\mathbb{A}}\,$ be the said irreducible representation, with
  an element $\,g\,$ of the group $\,G\,$ mapped to an operator
  $\,{\mathbb{A}}_g\,$. If $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,$ is an intertwiner, i.e.,
  if $~{\mathbb{M}}\,{\mathbb{A}}_g\,=\,{\mathbb{A}}_g\,{\mathbb{M}}~$
       for $\,\forall\, g\in G\,$, then  $~({\mathbb{M}}\,-\,\lambda\,{\mathbb{I}})\,{\mathbb{A}}_g\,=\,{\mathbb{A}}_g\,({\mathbb{M}}\,-\,\lambda\,{\mathbb{I}})\,$,
  where $\,\lambda\,$ is any eigenvalue of $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,$, while
  $\,{\mathbb{I}}\,$ is the identity matrix. Schur's Second Lemma says
  that the matrix $\,({\mathbb{M}}\,-\,\lambda\,{\mathbb{I}})\,$ is
  either zero or nonsingular. The latter option, however, is excluded
  because the eigenvector corresponding to $\,\lambda\,$ is mapped by
  the operator
  $~({\mathbb{M}}\,-\,\lambda\,{\mathbb{I}})\,{\mathbb{A}}_g\,$ to
  zero. So this is a zero operator, and
  $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,=\,\lambda\,{\mathbb{I}}\,$.
       $\left.\qquad\right.$

${\mathbb{QED}}$

This proof works only for finite dimensions, because it requires a nonzero $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,$ to possess at least one nonzero eigenvalue.

A generalisation of Schur's first lemma to countable dimensions is *Dixmier's lemma*.

I present its formulation for group representations, because this is the language understandable to a physicist.

- Suppose that $\,V\,$ is a countable-dimension vector space over
  $\,{\mathbb{C}}\,$ and that $\,{\mathbb{A}}\,$ is a group
  representation acting irreducibly on $\,V\,$. If the intertwiner
  $\,{\mathbb{M}}\in\,$Hom$\,_C(V, V )\,$ commutes with the action of
  $\,{\mathbb{A}}\,$, then there exists a number $\,c\in{\mathbb{C}}\,$ for 
  which $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,-\,c\,{\mathbb{I}}\,$ is not invertible on the space 
  $\,V\,$.

Proof

To employ *reductio ad absurdum*, start with an assumption that the map $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,-\,c\,{\mathbb{I}}\,$ is invertible for $\,\forall c\in {\mathbb{C}}\,$.
 Then, for any non-zero polynomial
  $$\,P(x)\,=\,(x-p_1)\,(x-p_2)\,.\,.\,.\,(x-p_N)\,\;,$$
 invertible is the map
 $$\,P({\mathbb{M}})\,=\,({\mathbb{M}}\,-\,p_1\,{\mathbb{I}})\,({\mathbb{M}}\,-\,p_2\,{\mathbb{I}})\,.\,.\,.\,({\mathbb{M}}\,-\,p_N\,{\mathbb{I}})\,\;,$$
 because the composition of invertible maps is invertible.

Consider all rational functions $\,R(x)\,=\,P(x)/Q(x)\,$, with $\,P(x)\,$ and $\,Q(x)\,$ complex-valued polynomials in a complex variable $\,x\,$.
 Defined on $\,{\mathbb{C}}\,$ except an unspecified finite subset (allowed to vary with each function), they constitute a space $\,{\mathbb{C}}(x)\,$ over $\,{\mathbb{C}}\,$. While the space $\,{\mathbb{C}}[x]\,$ of polynomials is of countable dimensions over $\,{\mathbb{C}}\,$, the space $\,{\mathbb{C}}(x)\,$ of rational functions is of uncountable dimensions.

For any $\,R(x)\,=\,P(x)/Q(x)\,$, there exists a map $\,R({\mathbb{M}})\,=\,P({\mathbb{M}})/Q({\mathbb{M}})\,$.
  Hence a map
 $$
 {\mathbb{C}}(x)\,\longrightarrow\,\mbox{Hom}_C\,(V,\,V)\,\;.
 $$

As we saw above, our initial assumption that the map $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,-\,c\,{\mathbb{I}}\,$ is invertible for $\,\forall c\in {\mathbb{C}}\,$ implies that all nonzero polynomials in $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,$ are invertible. For an invertible polynomial $\,Q({\mathbb{M}})\,$, invertible is the map $\,1/Q({\mathbb{M}})\,$. So the maps $\,R({\mathbb{M}})\,=\,\left(\,Q({\mathbb{M}})\,\right)^{-1}\,P({\mathbb{M}})\,$ are compositions of invertible transformations, and thus are invertible. Stated alternatively, if $\,v\in V\,$ is non-zero, then $\,R({\mathbb{M}})\, v\,=\,0\,$ necessitates $\,P({\mathbb{M}})v\,=\,0\,$.

This, in its turn, can be true only if $\,P\,$ is the zero polynomial:  $\;P(x)\,=\,0\;$ and, therefore, $\,R\,$ is the zero function, $\,R(x)\,=\,0\,$. In other words, only one element of the space $\,{\mathbb{C}}(x)\,$, the function $\,R(x)\,=\,0\,$, is mapped to the zero element $\,R({\mathbb{M}})\,=\,0\,$ of the space $\,\mbox{Hom}_C\,(V,\,V)\,$. Hence the map $\,{\mathbb{C}}(x)\,\longrightarrow\,\mbox{Hom}_C\,(V,\,V)\,$ is injection -- which implies that the dimensionality of $\,\mbox{Hom}_C\,(V,\,V)\,$ is uncountable, because such is the dimensionality of ${\mathbb{C}}(x)\,$. This, however, is incompatible with the assumption that $\,V\,$ is of countable dimensions.

${\mathbb{QED}}$

Now, my question.

We have proven that, for some $\,c\in{\mathbb{C}}\,$, the operator $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,-\,c\,{\mathbb{I}}\,$ is not invertible.

Can we now use Schur's second lemma, to state that $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,$  is a scalar multiple of the identity operator?

In finite dimensions, the noninvertibility of $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,-\,c\,{\mathbb{I}}\,$ is equivalent to $\,c\,$ being an eigenvalue of the matrix $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,$. However, in infinite dimensions this is not necessarily so. When  $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,-\,c\,{\mathbb{I}}\,$ is noninvertible (while the linear operator $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,$ is bounded), $\,c\,$ is said to belong to the spectrum of $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,$ -- which does not necessitate it being an eigenvalue. An operator on an  infinite-dimensional space may have a nonempty spectrum and, at the same time, lack eigenvalues.

Despite this circumstance, will it be legitimate to say that, if

- $\exists\,c\in{\mathbb{C}}\,$ for which $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,-\,c\,{\mathbb{I}}\,$ is not invertible,
- $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,-\,c\,{\mathbb{I}}\,$ is an intertwiner of an irreducible representation to itself,
- Schur's second lemma works in all dimensions,

then $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,-\,c\,{\mathbb{I}}\,=\,0\,$ and $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,$ is proportional to the identity operator?

Comment: Why would it not be legitimate ?

Comment: @Max I don't know!  In the books, Dixmier's lemma is given in the form "M - c Id is not invertibe", not in the simpler form M = c Id. Is this merely a tradition or is there some rationale behind it?

Comment: Doesn't the conclusion that $M=c Id$ follow the given statement ? Stated e.g. as a corollary ?

Comment: @Max : In finite dimension, this is definitely so. In infinite dimensions, it is not that obvious -- please see what I wrote in my question

Comment: No it obviously follows logically, I meant does it follow in the books ? (your argument is perfectly fine)

Comment: @Max : In the books, I saw the lemma only in the "minimal" form I cited above. See, e.g., page 100 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.2578 where the explanation follows N. R. Wallach, Real Reductive Groups I, Academic Press, Boston1988

Comment: This document explicitly (lemma 99) says that $T$ is a scalar multiple of $id$

Comment: @Max : oh hell, what an idiot i am.  Missed that one. Thank you!!

Comment: @MaximeRamzi  I heard that in Hilbert spaces $T = c$ Id
even in uncountable dimensions.  Do you happen to know if this is true?  Or with whom to consult on this?  Or where to look it up?

Comment: On a Hilbert space, the spectrum of any bounded operator is non-empty - so if you assume that $T$ is bounded, the same proof will go through. This fact about spectra of bounded operators should be in standard textbooks about Hilbert spaces

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Is my understanding correct that the non-emptinnes of spectrum of T implies the existence of $c$ for which $T-c$ Id is noninvertible?

Comment: Yes you're exactly right ! :)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I appreciate your help -- and your kind patience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it indeed is correct that Dixmier's lemma, together with Schur's lemma, entail the stronger statement that  $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,-\,c\,{\mathbb{I}}\,=\,0\,$ and, therefore, $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,$ is proportional to the identity operator.

See Lemma 99 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.2578 , where the story actually follows  N. R. Wallach `Real Reductive Groups. 1.'

Thanks to @Max who kindly drew my attention to that lemma.

Answer (score 1):

As an interesting aside, it should be added that
 Dixmier's generalisation of Schur's First Lemma works for countable dimensions only.

In uncountable dimensions, intertwiners from a representation to itself are *not* warranted to be scalar multiples of the identity. This can be illustrated by a counterexample kindly offered to me by Jacob Tsimerman.

Let the uncountable-dimensional space $\,V\,$ be implemented by the field $\,{\mathbb{C}}(x)\,$ of rational functions in $\,x\in{\mathbb{C}}\,$. Let the role of a group representation $\,{\mathbb{A}}\,$ acting on this space be played by the same field $\,{\mathbb{C}}(x)\,$. A rational function acts on a rational function by multiplication, to render another rational function. Then any nonzero element of $\,V\,$ generates all of $\,V\,$, wherefore $\,V\,$ is irreducible. Now, take $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,$ to be any non-zero integer power of $\,x\,$, e.g., $\,{\mathbb{M}}\,=\,x\,$. Not being a scalar multiple of the identity, this map commutes with the action of any operator $\,{\mathbb{A}}\;$.